# Fail to use language class to set custom message in form_validation.php in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started to use Codeignite 3 in my side project recently and I got a question of using language class.

Here're 3 files from my project.

1. /config/form_validation.php
2. /controllers/login_controller.php
3. /language/english/form_validation_lang.php

**login_controller.php**

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    ... do something
}
```

**form_validation_lang.php**

```
$lang['password_required'] = 'Please insert a password.';
```

**form_validation.php**

```
$config = array(
    array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => 'lang:password_required',
            ),
    )
);
```

All default error messages are shown in the view besides `lang:password_required`. How can I use the language class in `errors` parameters(it works for label)?

Thanks very much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->lang->load('form_validation', 'english');

$config = array(
    array(
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'Username',
            'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'required',
            'errors' => array(
                    'required' => $CI->lang->line('password_required'),
            ),
    )
);
```